# How do I set the correct breakpoint for v-main in vuetify? (or remove the left padding on v-main)

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a very typical application with a sidebar that collapses when the display width gets small, then uses a bottom drawer for smaller viewports. The issue I am seeing is thet the padding on v-main is 256 until the breakpoint gets to be `sm`. How can I change this padding?

This is the collapsed menu with the 256px padding, between `sm` and `large`:

[image: This is the collapsed menu with the 256px padding, between sm and large]

This is the screen at full width:

[image: This is the screen at full width]

Comment: Could you share the code on how you're using v-navigation-drawer, v-app and v-main? The left padding is likely from v-navigation-drawer being used incorrectly or at a wrong place, so the positioning doesn't update for v-main when it's reduced to the mini-variant.

Comment: Thank you, Excalibaard, your comment made me go throught the docs again. It looks like the way I am using the nav drawer is a bit off and needs to be updated with the current props/values instead of the old ones I am using. I will post here my solution when I get it working.